# tf between pointcloud and world frame

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

Instead of using freenect_launch package, I published all depth_image_proc required images and infos by myself and successfully generated pointcloud since I can echo specified topic and it did have response. The problem right now is when I want to use pointcloud to generate actomap in moveit, I assume since I lose the tf between pointcloud and world, the message will always drop. But because I don't know what frame name of pointcloud, I don't know what I should write down when I launch tf publisher. Any idea for how to get the frame name of my pointcloud? Thanks in advance for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283453/tf-between-pointcloud-and-world-frame/) by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're publishing the images yourself should be setting the frame_ids in your code. Or else it's a parameter on the intermediate pipeline. You can always find out the frame_id on a message by looking at the output of `rostopic echo` .

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2018-02-22**:
Got it. So the frame_id is specified in the header of message. Right now after launch tf between world and pointcloud in move_group.launch, when I run rviz, it always crashed because of failure to call service /get_planning_scene. But I did launch move_group.launch. Any idea? Thanks for reply.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-02-22**:
That's an separate question, please ask it separately and provide full details on how to reproduce your problem. Advise of asking good questions can be found at http://wiki.ros.org/Support The better your question the better your answer.